# <div>'s are moving up when window horizontally resized

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three divs each with a `<p>` element nested inside.

`

```
<div id="mainHeader">
<img id="mainThumbnail" src=    "../Pictures/myWebsite/mainThumnail-cropped.png" alt="D&D setup">
    <div id="mainContent">
    <h2>This is the title of an article</h2>
    <p>this is the content of the article. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco   laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div id="secondContainer">
 <img src="../Pictures/Gamerati/00-Freud.jpg" alt="Freud everyone!">
    <div id="secondArticle">
        <p>
        <span style="font-weight:bold;">This is another article.</span>
        this is the content of the article. L
        orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
        </p>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div id="thirdArticle">
<p>
    <span style="font-weight:bold;">This is yet another article</span>

this is the content of the article. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
</p>
```

`

(sorry if that's bad stylistically)

What I'm seeing is the paragraphs will move up on the screen when the window is squeezed vertically and `<p>` element has to put less words on each line to fit within the set margins. So now the paragraphs are vertically longer. Is there anyway to have the paragraphs "push down" the page with this extra length instead of grow upwards?

Here's the CSS:

```
#frontPage{
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    max-width:800px;
    height:800px;   
}

#frontPage p{
    background-color:#7C7C7C;   
}  

#frontPage h4{
     background-color:#7C7C7C;  
 }

 #mainContent{
    position:absolute;
    width:50%;
    text-align: center; 
    border-right: medium;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-right-color:#000000;
    margin-top:15%;
 }


#mainContent p {
    margin-left:12%;
    margin-right:12%;
    background-color:#7C7C7C;   
}

#secondArticle{ 
    text-align:center;
    width:20%;
    float:right;
    margin-top:27%;
 }


#thirdArticle{
    text-align:center;
    width:20%;
    float:right;
    clear:both; 
 }

#secondContainer {
    background-color:#7C7C7C;   
}

#secondContainer img{
    width:15%;
    margin-top:40%;
    float:left;
}
```

I thought about making an onWindowResize listener, but any type of off set would be completely up to trail and error.

Comment: what is the reason for using a percentage for `margin-top`?

Comment: None. I went back and changed them to specific pixel lengths and the problem went away. I though using a percent height would be more "encompassing". I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
#frontPage{
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    max-width:800px;
    height:800px;   
}
```

`position:aboslute;` and use vh instead of %

```
#secondArticle{ 
    text-align:center;
    width:20%;
    float:right;
    margin-top:27vh;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a specific pixel length instead of percentage and the problem went away. I also had a div tag out of place. Write code carefully, kids.

Comment: using specific pixel length however does not make your site responsive. You could use vh or vw :)